# Downloaded Ziggeo videos corrupt?

Tags: node.js, express, corruption

I'm on Windows 8.1 running node 10.22, express 4.11.2

I'm trying download a file from the Ziggeo API, but the resulting file comes out corrupt.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/download/:id',function(req,res){
    downloadVideo(req.params.id,res);
});

function downloadVideo(id,res){
    sdk.Videos.download_video(id,function(back){
        fs.writeFile('downloadedVideo.mp4',back,function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.sendStatus(400);
            }else{
                res.sendStatus(200);
                res.end();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The resulting file is corrupt and cannot be played.

When I download the same video using the Ziggeo dashboard, the filesize is bigger and I can play it back fine.

If I open the two files as text files and diff them, there are a few lines of similarities, but the files are largely different.

I've tried all three encoding types that `writeFile` takes as a parameter, but none of those help.

I also tried the `Streams.download_video` method, and that gives the same results.

Comment: Someone should make a Ziggeo tag, unless people just use the paid support features instead of SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the updated SDK on GitHub:

https://github.com/Ziggeo/ZiggeoNodeSdk

Answer (score 0):

Check the data that `sdk.Videos.download_video` passes to your callback. I expect that you are recieving JSON data (or some other data type), but are expecting a `H.264` video. The Ziggeo API documentation states:

> Whenever you interact with Server SDK, the Client API or Webhooks, you will receive resource objects from our system.

Try running `file` on your output video to identify what filetype you end up with

See [The Ziggeo docs](http://ziggeo.com/reference)

Comment: I can do `console.log(back)`, and it gives me back a bunch of garbled characters, so I don't think it's giving me back json. How do I run `file` on my output video?

Comment: `file` is a Linux/Unix tool that can identify file formats. It does so by scanning the file itself versus looking at the file extension. [Screenshot of usage](http://cl.ly/image/1w191j3u0627/Image%202015-02-17%20at%202.38.50%20PM.png).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm on Windows

Comment: Also, on the Ziggeo docs page you linked, under the Download Video method, it says it returns "DATA", as opposed to "JSON"